# How to update record if no image is added in Laravel and VueJs application

Tags: laravel, vue.js

For the update of my post table I want to add a validation to check if an image was uploaded. If no image is uploaded, everything is uploaded except the image, else it means there is an image and that is update.

I tried this in my Controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    if(request('photo')){
        $exploded = explode(',', request('photo'));
        $decoded = base64_decode($exploded[1]);
        if(str_contains($exploded[0], 'jpeg'))
            $extension = 'jpg';
        else
            $extension = 'png';   

        $fileName = str_random().'.'.$extension;
        $path = public_path().'/'.$fileName;
        file_put_contents($path, $decoded);
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $post->title = request('title');
        $post->description = request('description');
        $post->category_id = request('category_id');
        $post->user_id = Auth::id();
        $post->photo = $fileName;
        $post->save();
    }
    else{
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        $post->title = request('title');
        $post->description = request('description');
        $post->category_id = request('category_id');
        $post->user_id = Auth::id();
        $post->save();         
    }

    return response()->json([
        'post' => $post,
    ], 200);
}
```

In my vue file I have the following:

```
editPost(){
  if(this.update_post.photo == ''){
    axios.put('/api/posts/' + this.update_post.id, {
      title: this.update_post.title,
      description: this.update_post.description,
      category_id: this.update_post.category_id
    })
    .then(response => {
        alert('updated');
        this.showPosts();
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });            
  }
  else{
    axios.put('/api/posts/' + this.update_post.id, {
      title: this.update_post.title,
      description: this.update_post.description,
      category_id: this.update_post.category_id,
      photo: this.update_post.photo
    })
    .then(response => {
        alert('updated');
        this.showPosts();
    })
    .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
    });             
  }
}
```

When I try to update a post, if no image is inserted I get 500 Internal server error:

```
app.js:14233 PUT http://myblog.local/api/posts/52 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The below are some of the errors I see in the error log:

```
[2018-06-27 20:55:48] local.ERROR: Undefined offset: 1 {"userId":11,"email":"sidney@lab.com","exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined offset: 1 at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminPostsController.php:66)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminPostsController.php(66): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined offse...', 'C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', 66, Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminPostsController->update(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), '53')
#2 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller.php(54): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher.php(45): Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller->callAction('update', Array)
#4 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(212): Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(App\\Http\\Controllers\\AdminPostsController), 'update')
#5 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Route.php(169): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->runController()
#6 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(665): Illuminate\\Routing\\Route->run()
#7 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#8 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#9 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#10 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#11 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken.php(67): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#12 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#14 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#15 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\View\\Middleware\\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#17 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession.php(63): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#18 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Session\\Middleware\\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#20 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#21 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#23 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#24 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Cookie\\Middleware\\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#26 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#27 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(667): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#28 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(642): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route), Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#29 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(608): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->runRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Route))
#30 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Router.php(597): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#31 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#32 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#33 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\fideloper\\proxy\\src\\TrustProxies.php(57): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#34 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#35 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#36 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#37 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#38 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#39 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest.php(31): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#40 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#41 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#42 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#43 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#44 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#45 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(51): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#46 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(151): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))
#47 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#48 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline.php(104): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#49 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#50 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#51 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\sidneyblog\\public\\index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#52 {main}
"}
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, the condition `if(request('photo'))` is always true.

To [Retrieving Input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input) from the request use `Request $request` variable. for example:

for file: `$request->file('photo')`;

for other text: `$request->input('description');`

Comment: I tried the controller logic but I still see the same error...The column is nullable in my table though.
And solution2 is not the exact logic, because in  case there is an image already, it will replace with an empty string. What I want is to save everything except the image in case no image is entered...but your logic says that the table will receive an empty string in case an image is not inserted.

Comment: could you re-produce the error and then share the last few lines from /your-project/storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: I just updated my question with those errors.( the last few lines)

Comment: the lines you added is not enough. you can clear laravel.log and then re-produce the error then share all of laravel.log.
the lines you've shared are just the stack trace...

Comment: to get input from request use `$request` variable. for example: for file `$request->file('photo');` and `$request->input('description');` for other text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173923/discussion-between-usama-and-nadj).